# How to correctly index data?

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp-question-answering

Help me please. I have a JSON file with the following structure.

```
{
    "question": [ ... ], 
    "answer": [ ... ]
},
{
    ...
}
```

The task is to make a request in the form of a text, so that he searches for questions that I index and in the form of a search result displayed the answers.

I want to index all question fields, but I don't know what to do with answer fields.

Can you please tell me what to do or at least where to read.

Comment: You can find a sample question/answer design in the official documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/parent-join.html

Comment: @Val Thanks for the answer! I'm going to get acquainted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should give you a general overview of how mappings work in Elasticsearch.

I would first advise you to convert your json file into multiple JSON objects containing this structure:

```
{
  "question":"What is the meaning of life?",
  "answer":"42."
}
```

And your index would look something like this:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings":{
    "myFirstMapping": {
      "properties": {
        "question": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "standard"
        },
        "answer": {
          "type":"text",
          "index": "false"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Based on the text, language or special requirements you can later build a more complex analyzer, so far you are just using the standard one: [Standard Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/analysis-standard-analyzer.html)

See how in the field **answer** we specified it is not included in the index, this means that we will not search on the answer field, therefore it makes no sense to analyze it.

You can then proceed to index each pair of question/answer in this way:

```
POST my_index/myFirstMapping
{
  "question":"What is the meaning of life?",
  "answer":"42."
}
```

Finally, you can perform a search like the following:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "question": "life?"
    }
  }
}
```